# Proving absolute inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $b$ is an integer and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are positive integers such that:
$0 < r_1 < |b|$ and $0 < r_2 < |b|$.

Prove that :  $|r_1 - r_2| < |b|$

Answer (score 1):

$r_1\lt|b|$ and $r_2\gt0$ means that $r_1-r_2\lt|b|$

$r_2\lt|b|$ and $r_1\gt0$ means that $r_2-r_1\lt|b|$

Therefore, $|r_1-r_2|\lt|b|$